# AVL Insert and balance loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, avl-tree

I am implementing AVL Trees in C++ on my own code but this problem is more about **understanding** AVL trees rather than the code itself. I am sorry if it doesn't fit here but I have crawled through the Internet and I have still not found a solution to my problem.

My code works as expected with relatively small inputs (~25-30 digits) so I suppose it should work for more. I am using an array in which I hold the nodes I have visited during Insertion and then using a while loop I am raising the heights of each node when needed, I know that *this procedure has to end* when I find a node whose *heights are equal* (their subtraction result is 0 that is).

The problem is when it comes to balancing. While I can find the *Balance Factor* of each node and balance the tree correctly **I am not sure if I should stop adjusting the heights after balancing and just end the Insertion loop** or keep going until the condition is meant, and I just can't figure it out now. I know that during deletion of a node and re-balancing the tree I should keep checking but I am not sure about Insertion and balancing.

Anyone can provide any insight to this and perhaps some documentation?

Comment: Do you have Internet access only to this site? what about a Google Search "AVL Tree"? You get detailed explanation with source code, as in my updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference of future readers there is **no** need to edit the heights of the nodes above the node you balanced if you have implemented the binary tree like my example:

```
           10
        (1)/ \(2)
         8   16
          (1)/ \(0)
            11 

(Numbers in parenthesis are the height of each sub tree)
```

Supposing than on the tree above we insert a node with `data=15` Then the resulting subtree is as following:

```
           10
        (1)/ \(2)
         8   16
          (1)/ \(0)
            11
        (0)/  \(1)
              15
```

Notice how previous heights of sub trees are not yet edited. After a successful insertion we run back through the insertion path, in this case its `(11, 16, 10)`. After running back through this path we edit the heights when needed. That means the **left height of the sub tree of 16 will be 2** while it's **right height of sub tree is 0** resulting in an imbalanced AVL tree. After balancing the tree with a double rotation the sub tree is:

```
             15
         (1)/  \(1)
           11  16
```

So the subtree height is maximum 1, as it was before, therefore heights above the root of this subtree haven't altered and the function changing the heights must `return` now.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert only one item at a time:  Only one (single or double) rotation is needed to readjust an AVL tree after an insertion throws it out of balance. http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/avltrees/avltrees.html You can probably prove it by yourself after you know the conclusion.

Comment: Still this has nothing to do with my question. I am aware that one rotation is enough to make it AVL again, my question is after that rotation is performed do I have to adjust any node heights above the rotated node?

Comment: Yes, you need to update the heights after rotations. http://oopweb.com/Algorithms/Documents/AvlTrees/Volume/AvlTrees.htm